# AG Grid SSRM Tree Advanced Filtering

Tags: reactjs, treeview, ag-grid-react

Wondering if it is possible to enable advanced filtering in a grid which is presenting SSRM Tree Data (using React)? If so, are there any examples I can look at? Found nothing in the documentation...